# Extract text content from HTML without using InnerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML content and I am trying to extract the text. In the HTML content, I have gif images. Due to this the extract text process is taking longer time with InnerHTML.

Is there any way to extract text from HTML tags without using InnerHTML?

Right now I am using the below code.

```
 function extractText(html) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = html;
  return span.textContext || span.innerText;
}
```

Is there any alternative to above approach? Any regular expression we can use?

Comment: What are you passing to the function, a string or an element reference made from rendered html?

Comment: actually do `var textNode = document.createTextNode(html); span.appendChild(textNode)`

Comment: @DavePritlove Passing the HTML content to the function.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston  your method is not removing the html tags.

Comment: I guess I need to see the `html` variable value

Comment: @RonnieRoyston  <div style="color:red;"><p>This is test</p><img src="test.gif" /></div>

Comment: Try [`DomParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString). Maybe it won't load the images. Then read the `textContent` as before.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter passed to `extractText(html)` is a text string, your approach is right (assign the text to the `innerHTML` property of a created element but the thing you then want to extract, is the .innerText of that element. This property contains the text, minus any html tags.

Demo using a div as the created element (might be better than a span as it can hold any other element):

```js
const html="<div>debuggin is <span>not</span> fun</div>";

const holder = document.createElement('div');
holder.innerHTML = html;

console.log(holder.innerText);

const html2="<div style=\"color:red;\"><p>This is test</p><img src=\"test.gif\" /></div>"

const holder2 = document.createElement('div');
holder2.innerHTML = html2;

console.log(holder2.innerText);
```

Comment: How can we achieve without using innerHTML. If we have images, it is taking longer time to extract the text.

Comment: I don't understand how you can pass a string that contains an image. Are you infact passing an element object extracted from a rendered web page?

Comment: Images are loaded by the browser, html markup containing an image tag does not contain any image information and the image file contents never become part of the html, they are rendered within the html on the web page. In other words, if something is slowing your function down, it is not likely to be the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var html = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
```

```js
(function(){

var html = "<div style=color:red><p>This is test</p><img alt=test src=test.gif></div>"

extractText(html);

function extractText(html) {
const span = document.createElement('span');
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlParsed = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

let text = htmlParsed.querySelector("p").textContent

  span.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}


})();
```

Comment: It is extracting HTML tags. I need text. How can I do that?

Comment: This would take even more time to "extract," since you're parsing the HTML *again*

Comment: if it's coming in as parsed HTML already, just .querySelector.textContent